# How to disable animation JUST for the dock?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dash-to-dock

How can I disable animations for the dock? I know how I can disable them for the whole desktop, but is there any way I can do it for only one extension?

I'm getting a really annoying bug where the background of the focused app is blurry, and when animations are disabled it doesn't happen.

Using Ubuntu 22.04